# Argument passed to $modal is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using angularjs UI I'm trying to pass an argument to my modal.

The thing is, item is undefined. I've checked out the documentation etc. and I don't get what I'm doing wrong here.

The controller 'newproject' is the one calling the following code:

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/projects/createTask.html',
                controller: 'createtask as vm',
                resolve: {
                    item: function () {
                        return 'itemValue';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Inside the 'createtask' controller I have the following code (the beginning is displayed here):

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

        var controllerId = 'createtask';

        angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
            ['common', '$modalInstance', createtask]);

        function createtask(common, $modalInstance, item) {
        //why is item is undefined here?!?!?!
```

Note that the 'newproject' controller is located inside 'newProject.js' while the 'createtask' controller createTask.js.

For the sake of completeness, here are the complete controllers:

newProject.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'newproject';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
        ['$location', '$modal', '$routeParams', '$window', 'common', 'config', 'datacontext', 'utility', projectdetails]);

    function projectdetails($location, $modal, $routeParams, $window, common, config, datacontext, utility) {
        var vm = this;

        function editTask(task) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/projects/createTask.html',
                controller: 'createtask as vm',
                resolve: {
                    item: function () {
                        return 'itemValue';
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (newTask) {
                task = newTask;
                vm.projectCost += newTask.cost;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

createTask.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'createtask';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
        ['common', '$modalInstance', 'item', createtask]);

    function createtask(common, $modalInstance, item) {

        if (item) {
            alert(item);
        } else
            alert('undefined');
    }

})();
```

Comment: You need to list item as well in the dependency list.. Your number of arguments in the dep list must match the one in the constructor. Typo?

Comment: @PSL
Whenever I add 'item' to the array of dependencies I get an error saying "unknown provider: itemprovider".

Comment: When you open in a modal?

Comment: @PSL
Inside another controller. Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @PSL
Updated my question with the complete code of my controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding 'item' to the array in your controller definition:

```
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
        ['common', '$modalInstance', 'item', createtask]);
```

Comment: Whenever I add 'item' to the array of dependencies I get an error saying "unknown provider: itemprovider".

Comment: Where else are you using the controller?  The modal provider is the one injecting 'item' so if you use it outside the scope of a modal, say on a view or something, that will happen.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code of the controllers as well. Note that they are in separate files.

Comment: Can you maybe create a plunk or fiddle showing the error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found the item is undefined because there is no initial value.

```
$scope.showDialog = function () {
    var aModalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "yourPage.html",
        controller: "yourModalCtrl",
        resolve: {
           item: function () {
               **return null;// get an undefined error message**
               **return {firstName:"Superman"} // this one should be ok**                   
           }
        }
    });

   aModalInstance.result.then(function (val) {
       //not important
   }, function () {
       $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
   });
};

    ==>

app.controller("yourModalCtrl", function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {            
    $scope.firstName = item.firstName;    

    $scope.ok= function () {
        $modalInstance.close({firstName:$scope.firstName});
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```